# How to Adjust label size to change according to screen size

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

So I have 3 textFields, which I want to change the height according to which phone. For example, the label height increases if it's an iPhone 8+ vs an iPhone 8. This is my current code:

```
 let screensize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    expenseLabel.frame.size.height = screensize*0.1
    amountLabel.frame.size.height = screensize*0.1
    dateLabel.frame.size.height = screensize*0.1
```

However, this seems to have no effect on my code and it still displays the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use size classes to support different size for different screens. Here is a good tutorial about using size classes :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started